# Cordova (Android) device motion and device orientation (W3C) not available

Tags: android, cordova, devicemotion

I am trying to use [W3C device orientation](https://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/) and device motion in a Cordova app since [plugins](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion) are now deprecated. But there are no `DeviceOrientationEvent` defined in `window` nor event triggered when adding this snippet:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
    // process event.alpha, event.beta and event.gamma
}, true);
```

Here are some specs of my Android device:

```
Device model: JSN-L23
Cordova version: 8.0.0
Device platform: Android
Device manufacturer: HUAWEI
Device version: 9
WebGL support: true
User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; JSN-L23 Build/HONORJSN-L23; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Mobile Safari/537.36
Android WebView package name: com.google.android.webview
Android WebView version code: 372913600
Android WebView version name: 74.0.3729.136
```

Answer (score 0):

Use outside ondeviceready, somehow this event is disappering from windows object after deviceready is fired